# Very few ads showing through AdMob

Tags: ios, admob

I have a trending game, currently 2nd most downloaded in my AppStore, it uses banner ads by AdMob at the bottom of the screen, but the thing is very VERY few ads are showing (probably shown to 4-5% of the users who play the game)... I mean so few ads are showing that even the app was initially rejected by Apple because no third party ads where shown as stated in the App submission... Is this normal? How do I fix it? I see that it earns some cents so you can tell ads do show up although obviously not enough no earn even a dollar a day.

Any help please?

Edit: statistics just came out:

Estimated earnings
    €0.45
Impressions
    51,556
Request RPM
    €0.01

How should I read this data?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your ad implementation. AdMob has a near 100% fill rate so I doubt this is an AdMob issue. Edit your question to include your code.

Answer (score 1):

Add some other ad networks and use Admob to mediate between them. This will increase the number of ads available to your app and ensure you always serve up the ad that provide the best value to you.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the standard mechanism to remedy the issue with low fill rates. Which is the issue being experienced.